# Certificate not found while signing UWP package for Windows Store

Tags: uwp, certificate, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to sign a UWP package for the Windows store. I have a certificate that I installed virtually in every store in the "Certificate import Wizard". When I'm trying to select it from the Manifest designer inside Visual Studio I found this empty screen:
 [image]

I don't want to generate a new test certificate as this cert is working properly in other machines. Any ideas what is happening? I find very frustrating the signing certificate process in UWP apps, there is always going wrong in here, or there is little support from tools. Thanks.

Comment: What if you select the certificate from the file instead of the certificate Store? Can you see the certificate when you choose the certificate file?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to add a certificate in order to publish to the Microsoft Store. When you submit your app, it will automaticly sign it as part of the certification process.

Comment: Hi, I created a package for MS Store but when I run the WACK test with it, the test don't run. It said I don't have the package digitally signed. Any idea what am I missing? ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838384/wack-test-fail-the-app-bundle-must-be-digitally-signed-for-signature-validatio )