# Wack test fail. "The app bundle must be digitally signed for signature validation"

Tags: uwp

I am stuck on running the WACK test. It give me this warning before any testing.

> The app bundle must be digitally signed for signature validation.

[image]

According to the doc ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps )

> If you're publishing your app in Microsoft Store, your app will be
> signed with a trusted certificate for you. This allows the user to
> install and run your app without installing the associated app signing
> certificate.

However, the package I got from VS publish wizard seems not getting signed correctly.

I have read a related topic ([Windows Store App Certification Toolkit: The app bundle must be digitally signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63275358/windows-store-app-certification-toolkit-the-app-bundle-must-be-digitally-signed)) but the suggestion there use sideloading which is not my case.

In the "Create App Package" wizard, it asked

> How will you distribute this application?

I choose the first

> Microsoft Store as XXX by XXX

because I am building for a release on the store. There is no option about signing. I suppose it will sign with a right cert automatically since I already associated the app to my developer account.

This page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-certificate-package-signing) talks about how to create a certificate but that is only for local test. It does not mention a certificate for release.

This page about sign tool (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/sign-app-package-using-signtool) mentioned

> Once your app package is signed with a valid certificate, you're ready
> to upload your package to the Store. For more guidance on uploading
> and submitting apps to the Store, see App submissions.

I am not sure if it means I need to sign my package by myself. Even if it is the case, I have no idea where to download or create a certificate for release.

The packaging tab under appxmanifest:

[image]

The fields are all none. When clicked "Select from Store", it show:

[image]
Looks like there is no certificate associated with the application even on the Partner Center.

My question is, why is there no certificate? I already create a app in the partner center and filled out everything just waiting for the package upload. How do I get the package signed?

I also tired building the app on another PC with fresh installed VS and the issue still remain.

Update:

I tried the whole thing with a new empty UWP project and a new app entry in Partner Center but the issue still remains. This is so frustrating.

Comment: Looks like you are packaging your app using VS following the document, right? Is the WACK test a local test? Or you have already uploaded your package to the store?

Comment: Yes, I am following the doc to make the package. The WACK test is a local test right after step 9 of "Create your app package upload file using Visual Studio" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#generate-an-app-package). I didn't upload the file because I could not get the WACK test to run.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you have associated your app with the store?

Comment: I have associated the app with the store. Otherwise, I would not be able to choose "Microsoft Store as AppName by Company" option from the wizard.

Comment: You might need to renew your certificate to solve this. Could you please re-associate your app with the store and try it agian?

Comment: Just tried re-associate my app to the store and rebuild. It is still not digitally signed when running the follow up WACK test after a successful build.

Comment: Do you have another device that installed Visual Studio and try to package your app in that device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236218/discussion-between-nick-and-roy-li-msft).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of try and error, the cause is identified to be Visual Studio. It failed to get the certificate for signing the package. I am surprise there is no error message on the build log. As of this writing, I am using the latest Visual Studio 2019 version.

After using the Visual Studio 2022 preview, the package finally got signed correctly and passed the WACK test!

Roy Li. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: I am having the same problem with the WACK tool using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition, but I would need to contact my IT department to get an upgrade, and even then, you've had this issue in VS 2019, so I think I would need a license for the preview. Is there another workaround possibly?

Comment: I am having the same problem, tried with VS 2019 and VS 2022, but no success, is there any work around?